# Упорядоченный массив в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Задан какой-то массив из цифр (JavaScript). Надо проверить,если удалить один элемент из массива,то станет ли массив упорядоченным? (Например - [1,4,2,3] - не упорядоченный,если удалить цифру 4,то тогда станет упорядоченным - [1,2,3]).Если есть такой элемент,удалив который,массив станет упорядоченным,то - return true ,если нет - return false. Надо проверить все варианты массивов,то-есть написать такую программу,который будет работать на всех вариантов массив.(Примеры массивов - [0,0,0,0],[0],[1,1,1],[1],[1,2,3],[2,3,4,5,4],[] и т.д. )
  Эта работающая программа,но есть варианты массивов на которых оно не работает...

//JavaScript kod

```
function solution1(x) {
  if(x.length == 0 || x.length == 1) return false;
 let p = true;

  for(let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
  let y = x.slice();
   y.splice(i,1)
  p = true;

  for(let j= 0; j < y.length; j++){
    if (y[j+1] && y[j]>y[j+1]) {

      p = false
    }
    if(j == y.length-1 && p == true){
      return true;
    }
  }    
  }
  return p;
}

console.log(solution1([]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, но пока что мне тоже не нравится немного.

```js
Array.prototype.isAscending = function(){
    return this.every( (v,idx) => idx > 0 ? v > this[idx-1] : true );
};


function check(data){
  var  i =0, asc = false;  
  do {     
     asc = data.filter( (v,idx) => idx != i).isAscending();
     if(asc) return true;         
  }
  while(++i < data.length)
  
  return false;
}

console.log ( check([4,5,2,3] ) );
console.log ( check([5,2,3] ) );
console.log ( check([2,3] ) );
console.log ( check([2,3,1] ) );
console.log ( check([2,3,1, -1] ) );
```

так пожалуй лучше будет.

```js
  Array.prototype.isAscending = function(){
        return this.every( (v,idx) => idx > 0 ? v > this[idx-1] : true );
    };


function check(data){
    return data.some( (v,i) => data.filter( (f,k) => k != i ).isAscending());                   
}


    console.log ( check([4,5,2,3] ) );
    console.log ( check([5,2,3] ) );
    console.log ( check([2,3] ) );
    console.log ( check([2,3,1] ) );
    console.log ( check([2,3,1, -1] ) );
```

Comment: спасибо,работает как надо))

Answer (score -1):

Вроде так. Не очень изящно, но, кажется, работает (во всяком случае, контрпримеров я не придумал):

```js
function solution1(x) {
  let anomalyCount = 0;
  return !x.some((num, i, arr) => {
    if (i > 0 && num < arr[i - 1]) {
      return anomalyCount++;
    }
    if (i > 1 && num < arr[i - 2]) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
}

console.log(solution1([])); // true
console.log(solution1([0])); // true
console.log(solution1([1, 2, 3, 4, 1])); // true
console.log(solution1([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])); // true
console.log(solution1([1, 2, 1, 2, 3])); // true
console.log(solution1([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1])); // false
console.log(solution1([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])); // false
```

Comment: спасибо,но это тоже не всегда работает правильно)))

Comment: А можно пример массива, на котором не работает?

Comment: на твоем примере ответов,почти во всех не работает,там у тебя true и false неправильные ответы

Comment: А еще конкретнее? Где именно неправильно, и почему?