# Есть ли в массиве элемент, при удалении которого массив будет упорядочен

Tags: javascript

Необходимо проверить, есть ли в массиве элемент, при удалении которого  массив будет упорядочен.

Например, в случае A = [1,3,2], если мы удалим 3, мы получим упорядоченный массив. Между тем, в случае A = [1,3,2,1], массив не превращается в упорядоченный при удалении произвольного элемента.

Необходимо написать функцию, которая получит массив и вернет true, если есть возможность удалить один элемент, получив в результате упорядоченный массив, и false в противном случае

```
JavaScript [5,6,7] true ,[2,4,2,1] false ,  [5,5,5,5] false
```

Comment: Стандартная задача. Гуглить «почти отсортированный массив».

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Упорядоченный массив в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933189/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        var mas=[]; 
      // создаем массив,в который будет записаны числа разрушающие упорядоченность
        var j=0; // служебная переменная, для индексации  массива mas
        if(array.length>1){
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
          {
            if(array[i]!=array[length-1]) 
               {
                 if(array[i]>array[i+1])mas[j]=array[i+1]; // 3,2->будет записан 3
                 j++;
               }
          }
        if(array[array.length-1]<array[0])
         {
           mas[j]=array[array[array.length-1]];
           j++;
         }
        }
// если там 1 число, то выводим тру, если там больше 1 числа или таких чисел нет-> false
        if(array.length==1)return true;
        return false;
```

Comment: А зачем вообще второй массив? Достаточно одного просмотра  исходного с вспомогательным индексом на конец упорядоченной последовательности и подсчетом количества элементов, нарушающих упорядоченность. Когда встречаете нарушителя, запоминаете его индекс. Если нарушение второй раз -- выход с false. И т.д.